# Is there a resource for setting up multiple structures for automatic delegate payouts for bakers?

Tags: baking, delegation

I am looking for a resource or method of accomplishing automated payouts from baker to delegates which allows for charging different delegates different fees.

For example lets say you charge friends and family a reduced rate compared to your regular rate. Or perhaps you are offering new delegates a reduced rate for a period of time.